# Restrict Index File In Machine

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I have a question about  file permission in linux .

Let's suppose I have hosted a index.php file in my machine. The file can be read in browser.But I wanted to make it such like it should be viewable in browser but should not accessible from my machine.
Is there any way so I can restrict someone to access it from my machine folder but can be read via browser?

P.S:- He/She has a low privileged shell.

Comment: You could always lock them from being able to access specific folders

Comment: Any linux commands or apache configuration you recommend?

Comment: Study how Linux / Unix permissions work. You can restrict access to just certain user or group. So maybe make it accessible only to the webserver user.

Comment: I know how permissions work. But it does not make what I trying to do.Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The webserver runs as some user, for example apache. Make the file owned by apache with permission 600. This makes it available to user apache and no-one else.

Comment: Thank you.This makes sense.